# Building app to display specific website for flutter, what is a substitution for WebView(initialUrl: 'abcd')

Tags: flutter, webview

Trying to build an app to display a specific website but only saw solutions for WebView(intialUrl: 'the url') but i think there is no longer a WebView class or a intialUrl field anymore, how should I deal with this? Thanks!

I tried using WebViewController and WebViewWidget but was confused about how they operate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem. Do you want to write a custom parser for html to flutter widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter doesn't provide webview class by default you should use one of the packages on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages?q=webview). If you want simple one use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and another famuse with many more features is [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview).
Here is a tutorial by Google can help https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-webview.

However you should provide an initial URL for the webview and you can control the webview and change the URL if you want from the webview controller that you store it in a local variable when the webview created (usually using field that take callback called onWebViewCreated or something like that)